# Call powersehell with parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this in a powershell

```
if (Test-Path env:\names)
{
    [string[]] $names= (dir env:\names).Value.Split(",") | % { $_.Trim() }
} else {
    [string[]] $names= "peter","mikael","Anders","William"
}

Write-Host -n "names: " ; [string]$names
```

If I would like to call it from command prompt is that possible?

I have tried this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File MainScript.ps1 -PARAM "Peter,Mikael"
```

I do understand that wont work since I am looking for a `env:names` but how can I make it work? What I am after is that I would like to send in a parameter with names and that should be caught in something like the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a complete mess here. First `env:names` means value of environment variable `names`, there shouldn't be `\`.

Then, if you want you script to accept parameters - just add `param(string[] $names)` as first line of your script

If you want to run your script with parameters - just start powershell and type: `full_path_to_script Peter,Mikael`

Comment: ok I am getting closer. So I have manage to make it work if I remove the if and else. How do I make it work that if I dont send anything at all it will be filled up with the default names?

Comment: if ($names -eq $null) {$names = "peter","mikael","Anders","William"}

Comment: It works....almost. If I print it the call will be: name,name  but the with default is "name","name","name","name"  Do you see the diffrence? It is a string array the last one. And that is what I want.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. If you still need help - update your question with clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
param($name)

if (Test-Path env:\names)
{
    $names = $env:names.Split(",") | % { $_.Trim() }
}
else
{
    $names = $name.Split(",") | % { $_.Trim() }
}

 Write-Host -n "names: $names"
```

Comment: And how would the call then look like?

Comment: powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File MainScript.ps1  "Peter,Mikael"